# aws setup jenkins behind bastion

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bastion-host

I have created a bastion server in public subnet and my Jenkins in private subnet within the same vpc. I am able to ssh into Jenkins from bastion host but unable to access the login.
I have created an ALB and registered the jenkins instance as the target. I verified the routing table, nacl and security group settings to access the jenkins server. I am still not able to access jenkins login and ALB target health checks (set up for /login) are failing with request timeout error.
Could you suggest what I could possibly missing?

TIA

Comment: What protocols and ports are you allowing for the Jenkins subnet ingress/egress? ssh and http are different protocols (normally) using different ports, so that could explain why one works but the other doesn't.

Comment: subnet ingress/egress have the default settings.